# how do I make a javascript reference work in nuxt3 that does not exist as an npm package?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt3

So I'm trying to embed tidycal into my nuxt3 website. the code snippet from tidycal looks like this

```
<script src="https://asset-tidycal.b-cdn.net//js/embed.js"></script>
<div id="tidycal-embed" data-path="xxxx/15-minute-meeting"></div>
```

when I put this into a vanilla .html page it works perfectly.

But in nuxt it doesn't allow the `<script src="https://asset-tidycal.b-cdn.net//js/embed.js"></script>` part in a .vue component.

So I searched the internet and apparently you have to use the "head()" method to do what I want to do.

```
<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
        {src: 'https://asset-tidycal.b-cdn.net//js/embed.js', body: true}
      ]
    }
  },
  // beforeMount() {
  //   console.log("mount mount");
  //   const script = document.createElement("script");
  //   script.type = "text/javascript";
  //   script.src = "https://asset-tidycal.b-cdn.net//js/embed.js";
  //   document.body.appendChild(script);
  // }
}
</script>
```

problem is: the head() method is gray in my IDE. As if some reference would be missing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s63z.jpg)
Also I found that in nuxt3 I should use the setup() function instead of the head() function, but setup() doesn't do anything either.

So I'm kinda desperate. It's actually not such a complicated thing but I can't find anything online that just helps me. It can't be that hard to load js references that come from a  tag instead of an npm package.

Thank you for helping me.